# Selecton.Rows.AutoFit does not work - why?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a problem with a piece of VBA code:

```
    Sub Macro3()
    Sheets("Output").Select
    Rows("5:160").Select
    Selection.Rows.AutoFit
    End Sub
```

What - from my point of view it should do - is applying Autosize to Rows 5:160 within the Sheet "Output". I added the code to the sheet "Output" so whenever I open it it should be properly resized automatically. However, nothing happens. But if I manually select the rows and press CRTL+C+H+O+A to auto size the rows it works properly.

Does anyone has a guess where the mistake lies? Would be a huge help!

Thanks upfront!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whenever I open it it should be properly resized automatically.

For this you have to place the code in the `ThisWorkbook` code area and you have to use the `Workbook_Open()` event

See this

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Output").Rows("5:160").Rows.AutoFit
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: In that case change `Workbook_Open()` to `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` and instead of `ThisWorkbook`, place it is the sheet code area.

Comment: One more thing: Do you know ad hoc whether there is an VBA command to add lines to rows in which content is located and leave out empty rows? Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry could you explain it a little bit more?